# emacsclient: unable to auto-detect email address (got '<my-user-name>@<my-machine-name>.(none)

Tags: git, emacs, magit, emacsclient

I cannot commit while using magit in emacsclient,
and when I expand the error, I see:

```
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got '<my-user-name>@<my-machine-name>.(none)')
```

N.B. I can commit normally when not using emacsclient (i.e. opening emacs directly from terminal.) My global git configs are set properly and I can commit from anywhere else without any problem. The problem arises when I try to commit using magit inside of emacsclient.

### Versions

emacs: GNU Emacs 28.2

doomemacs:
Doom core     v3.0.0-pre

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Windowing System: X11

Comment: (Disclaimer: I know nothing about emacsclient specifically.) If `git config --global` has the right settings, the only possible cause here would seem to be that your emacsclient code has un-set whatever variable(s) Git is using to locate your global config: `$HOME` and/or `$XDG_HOME`. Find some way to see what those are set to and if they're wrong or unset, figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `emacs` and `emacsclient` is that the former creates a process owned by the current user, while the latter requires a server (daemon), which could be started by either current user or system/root user.

Since you mention that not using `emacsclient` works fine, then I suspect the emacs server is being run by a user other than the current user, most likely root if you only have one user.